# PHP получает пустой массив при AJAX запросе

Tags: php, ajax

Отправляю AJAX запрос, но в PHP обработчик приходит пустой массив. Уже второй день сижу, все, что знал, перепробовал, ничего не помогает. Help, please!

Ajax запрос:

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('input.item_part-number');
    for (let elem of elements) {
        elem.addEventListener("change",()=>{
            let value = elem.value; 
            $.ajax({
                url: "newrequpdate.php", 
                type: "post",
                data: {'result': value},
                success: function (response) {
                console.log(value);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                console.error("Ошибка при отправке данных: ", error);
                },
                });
        })
    }
```

PHP обработчик:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
```

Вот, что распечатывается в браузере на странице php обработчика:

```
array(0) { }
```

Comment: *"Вот, что распечатывается в браузере на странице php обработчика:"* --- а почему вы смотрите это на странице обработчика, а не в консоли, как и должны?  ...и почему вы уверены, что в elem.value что-то есть?

Comment: И ещё вопрос, почему вы написали "post" в свойство `type`, почему она написана маленькими буквами и какую версию *Jquery* используете?

Comment: В консоли на странице обработчика результат тот же -  `array(0) { }`. То что, в elem.value что то есть вижу в Network Preview на странице ввода данных - `array(1) { ["result"]=> string(3) "789" }`.  POST исправил на больше, спасибо. Версия - jquery-3.6.0

Comment: прокатило POST, получается?

Comment: нет, все так же осталось :(

Comment: Надо поменять `type` на `method`, т.к. доккументация (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)  говорит  **type** - An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of **jQuery prior to 1.9.0**.

Comment: *"То что, в elem.value что то есть вижу в Network Preview"*  --- так "Preview" это то, что приходит от сервера... Значит всё же данные приходят. Получается проблемы нет

Comment: type на method исправил, результат тот же. "так "Preview" это то, что приходит от сервера.." - вопрос как увидеть эти данные на странице php обработчика? Мне же нужно с ним работать, а я их даже посмотреть не могу...

Comment: Их можно посмотреть двумя способами: **1)** через отладчик https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482   .... **2)** вначале сделать всё тоже самое без ajax, то есть запрос отправлять формой на php, наладить весь процесс, а потом заменить на ajax.....Лучше первым способом. Это настраивать долго, зато в будущем пригодится на 1000%   
 ..............Потому что вы не понимаете именно сам процесс взаимодействия клиент-сервера.... и вам надо прочитать как  оно работает......Сейчас вы пытаетесь позвонить в дверь квартиры, потом заходите в квартиру, а там звука нет)))

Comment: понял))) спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: Отладчик вначале просто настройте на чистом PHP коде. Потому что если он настроен, то при запросе откуда либо и установленном breakpoint  отладка сработает и потом, даже если запрос через ajax или ещё откуда либо

Comment: И это.... статья чуууууууууууточку усторела.... там для версии >=php8.0 нужен будет порт устанавливать не 9000, а 9003 вроде..... погуглите)